# Observer Pattern implementation without reciprocal references and smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Observer pattern, but i don't want observers being responsible for my program safety by maintaining the reference list in `ObservableSubject`.

Meaning that when the `Observer` `object` lifetime ends, I dont want to explicitly call `ObservervableSubject::removeObserver(&object)`.

I have come up with an idea to use use pointer references in `ObservableSubject`.

My question are: Is implementation described above and attempted below possible?
And what is happening in my program, how do i prevent dereferencing trash?

Apriori excuse: This is an attempt at understanding C++, not something that should have actual use or be prefered over other implementations.

My solution attempt:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ObserverInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ObserverInterface() {};
    virtual void handleMessage() = 0;
};

class ObservableSubject
{
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<ObserverInterface*>> listeners;

public:
    void addObserver(ObserverInterface* obs)
    {
        if (&obs)
        {
            // is this a reference to the copied ptr?
            // still, why doesnt my guard in notify protect me
            this->listeners.push_back(obs);
        }
    }

    void removeObserver(ObserverInterface* obs)
    {
        // todo
    }

    void notify()
    {
        for (ObserverInterface* listener : this->listeners)
        {
            if (listener)
            {
                listener->handleMessage();
            }
        }
    }
};

class ConcreteObserver : public ObserverInterface {
    void handleMessage()
    {
        std::cout << "ConcreteObserver: I'm doing work..." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ObservableSubject o;

    {
        ConcreteObserver c;
        o.addListener(&c);
    }

    o.notify();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Line in `ObservableSubject::notify()` :  `Listener->handleMessage()` throws the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
listener->**** was 0xD8BF48B. occurred
```

Comment: Are you looking for std::weak_ptr vs std::shared_ptr? This would provide the lifetime management of Subject, and allow stale observers to stay live holding "broken" weak_ptr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior.

```
ObservableSubject o;

{
    ConcreteObserver c;
    o.addListener(&c);  // Problem

}
```

`c` gets destructed when the scope ends. You end up storing a stale pointer in the list of listeners of `o`.

You can resolve the problem by defining `c` in the same scope as `o` or by using dynamically allocated memory.

```
ObservableSubject o;
ConcreteObserver c;
o.addListener(&c);
```

or

```
ObservableSubject o;

{
    ConcreteObserver* c = new ConcreteObserver;
    o.addListener(c);
}
```

When you use dynamically allocated memory, the additional scope is not useful. You might as well not use it.

```
ObservableSubject o;
ConcreteObserver* c = new ConcreteObserver;
o.addListener(c);
```

If you choose to use the second approach, make sure to deallocate the memory. You need to add

```
delete c;
```

before the end of the function.

---

#### Update, in response to OP's comment

You said:

> Maybe i wasn't clear. Solving the lifetime/stale pointer problem was the intention of my solution. I know i have no problems if i have properly managed lifetime, or if i add `detachObserver` option on Observer destruction. I want to somehow be able to tell from the `ObservableSubject` if his list of Observers was corrupted, without the Observer explicitly telling that.

Since dereferencing an invalid pointer is cause for undefined behavior, it is essential that you track the lifetime of observers and make sure to update the list of observers when necessary. Without that, you are courting undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear. Solving the lifetime/stale pointer problem was the intention of my solution. I know i have no problems if i have properly managed lifetime, or if i add detachObserver option on Observer destruction. I wan't to somehow be able to tell from the ObservableSubject if his list of Observers was corupted, without the Observer explicitly telling that.

Comment: So the answer to my question - Is implementation described above and attempted below possible? - is no? If so I'd like to wait a bit and accept your answer.

Comment: The answer is "No".

Comment: I appreciate the condescending tone. The question was to expand on my idea into a workable solution. Apparenty the idea is laughable, I just don't understand why you read through.

Comment: @AntonioDropulić, it wasn't my intention to be condescending. I am being as objective as I can be.

Comment: The condescending comment was not yours, it seems to be deleted now. I am sorry for the missunderstanding, I didn't reference the person. You have been very helpful and I am extremely appreciative of that.

Comment: One might say I really have a problem with dangling references :D

Answer (score 3):

Note, I don't recommend the following approach, but I think it meets your requirements. You have a duplicated observer list. One is under control of the Observers, and the other, using weak pointers, is handled by the Observable object.

1. Make the Observer constructors private and use an `ObserverFactory` (which is their friend) to obtain a `std::shared_ptr<Observer>`. The factory has a map from raw pointers to reference wrappers to the associated shared pointer.
2. The listeners list becomes `std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Observer>>`. On list traversal, you try to lock the weak_ptr; if it succeeds, handle the message; if it fails, that is, you get `nullptr`, remove the weak pointer from the list.
3. When the listener no longer wants to listen, it tells the Factory to do a `reset` on its shared pointer and remove from the map. This step is rather ugly, as it is just a fancy `delete this`, normally a code smell.

I believe you can also do this with `std::shared_from_this`.

The plan is you move the maintenance away from the ObservableSubject back into the Observers.

Answer (score 2):

> // is this a reference to the copied ptr?

Yes, it is. It invokes undefined behaviour because the `obs` pointer variable goes out of scope at the end of the function, resulting in a dangling reference.

The whole idea doesn’t gain you anything. Even if you make the ref-to-pointer approach work correctly, you are depending on one thing: That *that exact* pointer variable is set to `nullptr` once the object dies. Essentially that’s the same problem as ensuring that no dangling pointers are held in `listeners`.

For a heap object: How do you make sure that nobody deletes the object through a different pointer? Or forgets to null the registered pointer? It’s even worse for stack objects like in your example. The object goes out of scope and dies automatically. There is no opportunity to null anything unless you introduce an additional pointer variable that you’d have to manage manually.

You could consider two general alternatives to your approach:

- Make the relation bidirectional. Then whoever dies first (observable or observer) can notify the other party abouts its death in the destructor.
- If you don’t like the bidirectionality a central, all-knowing orchestrator that decouples oberservers and observables works, too. Of course that introduces some kind of global state.

Real-life implementations usually go in the general direction of leveraging C++ destructors for deregistration. Have a look at Qt’s signal/slot mechanism, for example.